# creating and using a dynamic shared library on solaris

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, solaris

I am reading the procedure to create and use a dynamic shared library on solaris sparc server.
below are the file i have :

```
> ls -lrt
total 8
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       848 Nov 22 14:45 badmemlib.hh
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody      1924 Nov 22 14:46 badmemlib.cc
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       330 Nov 22 14:49 my_prog.cc
>
```

in the above files badmemlib.hh is the header file using which i am creating a shared library with the below command following what is mentioned in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkamq.html) link.

```
> CC -G -o libbad.so -h libbad.so -Kpic badmemlib.cc
```

after i run the above command i have these below files:

```
> ls -lrt
total 26
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       848 Nov 22 14:45 badmemlib.hh
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody      1924 Nov 22 14:46 badmemlib.cc
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       330 Nov 22 14:49 my_prog.cc
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody      8284 Nov 22 15:11 libbad.so*
>
```

as you can see libbad.so is built without any errors.
Now my main is in the file my_prog.cc
i am compiling the file my_prog.cc as below which following  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkajr.html#bkajv):
and there were no errors.the binary  a.out is built.

```
> CC -L. -lbad my_prog.cc
> ls -lrt
total 184
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       848 Nov 22 14:45 badmemlib.hh
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody      1924 Nov 22 14:46 badmemlib.cc
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody       330 Nov 22 14:49 my_prog.cc
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody      8284 Nov 22 15:11 libbad.so*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody     80224 Nov 22 15:14 a.out*
>
```

Now if i run a.out then the error i am facing is :

```
> ./a.out
ld.so.1: a.out: fatal: libbad.so: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed
```

It mentions that library is not found but as you can see above the library is in the same directory!

Could anybody pls help me!

content of my_prog.cc.it actually generates a sigsegv and and the badmemlib files has a signal handler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "badmemlib.hh"
#ifdef SOLARIS /* needed with at least Solaris 8 */
#include <siginfo.h>
#endif

int main(){ 
        char *where=(char *)0x123;

        printf( "About to write to %p\n", where);
        strcpy(where,"vijay");

        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your application to find .so file from your current directory:

```
CC -L. -lbad my_prog.cc -R <your current directory>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkana.html#bkawi

Comment: I guess it should be -R and nor -r

Comment: it's -R, I put the CC document link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

You should be doing:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<full path where library is present>
```